Is there a difference between .then and .catch async error catching methods
I'm error-managing a lot of async functions (mostly API calls), so I'm wondering if there's some difference between these two error catching methods:
anyAsyncFunction().then().catch((err) => handleError(err))

anyAsyncFunction().then(() => {
   // logic
}, (err) => handleError(err))

I've seen both of these being used and have not yet understood the difference between them.
